# Issues with Save-AzureRmProfile

Tags: powershell, azure

I have created virtual machine in Azure and selected Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have installed windows PowerShell using the Web platform installer. When I try to run the following command:

```
Save-AzureRmProfile -Path C:\MyPath\myfile.json
```

It throws the error:

> The term 'Save-AzureRmProfile' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

I have tried to follow this link [here](https://regularitguy.com/2014/03/13/installing-the-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets/) by adding environments variables but no help. Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Save-AzureRmProfile` works on version 3.7. You could use the following cmdlet to check Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

You could download 3.7 version msi installer from this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.7.0-March2017).

Answer (score 2):

You have to Install the **Azure PowerShell** cmdlets. I suggest you to install it using the latest MSI from [this site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

---

It looks like the `Save-AzureRmProfile` cmdlet has been *replaced* by `Save-AzureRmContext`. I found that information [here](https://arcanecode.com/2017/04/19/what-happened-to-save-azurermprofile/).

Comment: Still no luck. I installed Azure PowerShell 4.0.1 but not working. Didnt understood what is use of remaining 2 links in that site

Comment: Did you restart your PowerShell?

Comment: i restarted pc as well

Comment: Whats the output of `Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where Name -like 'Azure*' |Select Name, Version`

Comment: There is lot of things in that output. what you need?

Comment: The Version of AzureRM.Profile if present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144538/discussion-between-developmentismypassion-and-martin-brandl).

Answer (score 1):

The name of the cmdlet was changed in 4.0, you can see all the changes in 4.0 here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/documentation/release-notes/migration-guide.4.0.0.md

Unfortunately, the name of the cmdlet was changed without an alias for backward compatibility in version 3.8, per this issue: .  This is actually a *bug* we will be pushing out a version 3.9 which is identical to 3.8, except that the two profile cmdlets (Save-AzureRmProfile, Select-AzureRmProfile) remove this breaking change

Answer (score 0):

Save-AzureRmContext and Import-AzureRmContext can be used for same purpose on Version 4.0
Usage is same!